# How to work with an Onclick event for outside div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some buttons inside of a DIV and need them to perform action on Outside DIV with onclick event to show the new DIV with hide/show.

It is working fine in the same div section (.coluna), but when I want to perform action to show a DIV that is outside the first DIV section (action between #botao_continuar_1 and #passo_2), it doesn't works.

It should go:

botao_ok > passo_1_2 > botao_continuar_1 > (show) passo_2 >...

botao_ok > passo_1_2 > botao_voltar_1 > (hide) passo_1_2

Live code on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fozd9b2s/1/

The code:

```
<div class="coluna">
                <!-- Item 1 -->
                <div class="item" id="passo_1">

                    <h2>Text 1</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                    <div class="botoes">
                        <div class="botao" id="botao_ok">Ok</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item2" id="passo_1_2">

                    <h2>Instrução 1.2</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                    <div class="botoes" id="botao_continuar">
                        <div class="botao2" id="botao_voltar_1">Voltar</div>
                        <div class="botao2" id="botao_continuar_1">Continuar</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="coluna">
                <!-- Item 2 -->
                <div class="item" id="passo_2">                   
                    <h2>Instrução 2</h2>
                        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>

                        <div class="botoes">
                            <div class="botao" id="botao_voltar_2"> Não </div>
                            <div class="botao" id="botao_continuar_2"> Sim </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item2" id="passo_2_1">

                    <h2>Instrução 2.1</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                    <div class="botoes">
                        <div class="botao2" id="botao_voltar_3">Voltar</div>
                        <div class="botao2" id="botao_continuar_3">Continuar</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
//-----------
        $("#botao_ok").on("click",function () {
            $("#passo_1_2").show("slow");
        });
        //
        $("#botao_voltar_1").on("click",function(){
            $("#passo_1_2").hide("slow");
        });
        $("#botao_continuar_1").on("click",function(){
            $("#passo_2").show("slow");
        });
//-----------
});
```

Comment: Consider posting requests for code review on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Your subsequent `.coluna` are hidden. You have to show those as well. Maybe add id to them and add another `.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this in your css:

```
.coluna:not(:first-child){
   display: none;
}
```

So all of your `.coluna`s except the first one are hidden. It doesn't matter if you show/hide any of their children until they are displayed themselves.

Comment: Thanks, it solved by adding an id to the .coluna div and placed a new .show on it, then I've added it to the function, like this:
`$("#coluna_hidden").show("slow");`

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Instruções de Reparo </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
```

```
<!--&&&&&&&&& container &&&&&&&&&-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="instrucoes">
        <div class="coluna">
            <!-- Item 1 -->
            <div class="item" id="passo_1">
                <h2>Instrução 1</h2>a
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                <div class="botoes">
                    <div class="botao" id="botao_ok">Ok</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item2" id="passo_1_2">

                <h2>Instrução 1.2</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                <div class="botoes" id="botao_continuar">
                    <div class="botao2" id="botao_voltar_1">Voltar</div>
                    <div class="botao2" id="botao_continuar_1">Continuar 1</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna" id="passo_2">
            <!-- Item 2 -->
            <div class="item" >

                <h2>Instrução 2</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>

                <div class="botoes">
                    <div class="botao" id="botao_voltar_2"> Não </div>
                    <div class="botao" id="botao_continuar_2"> Sim </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item2" id="passo_2_1">

                <h2>Instrução 2.1</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                <div class="botoes">
                    <div class="botao2" id="botao_voltar_3">Voltar</div>
                    <div class="botao2" id="botao_continuar_3">Continuar ss</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="coluna" id="passo_3">
            <!-- Item 3 -->
            <div class="item" >

                <h2>Instrução 3</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                <div class="botoes">
                    <div class="botao"> Não </div>
                    <div class="botao"> Sim </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item2" id="passo_3_1">

                <h2>Instrução 3.1</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna. </p>
                <div class="botoes">
                    <div class="botao2">
                        Continuar
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```